# Issue loading language file, CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have extended CI's baked in form validation, however I'm having issues loading a language files. I have the following code:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function __construct() {
        parent :: __construct();
        $this->load->lang('raf');

    }
```

However this throws the error:

> Call to a member function lang() on a non-object

Can anyone spot the issue here?

Answer (score 3):

To load language in codeigniter, Syntax is :

```
$this->lang->load('filename', 'language');
```

Not:

```
$this->load->lang();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try after load Helper file

```
$this->load->helper('language');
```